# How to create a regular, resizable grid without nested weights?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-tablelayout

I've one of the simplest layouts imaginable: A num pad.

I want to create a fragment containing a 3 x 4 grid of buttons. The layout should automatically resize the num pad to fill the available space.

I've learned, that GridLayout is not up to the task, and TableLayout/TableRow or nesting LinearLayouts means nesting weights, which is also discouraged for performance reasons. A RelativeLayout won't work either, because that requires at least one button with given dimensions.

So, is there a clean way to create a regular grid that will resize to fill its parent?

Any help is appreciated, thx!

Comment: Why didn't `GridLayout` work? (I've not used it much) Honestly, I would have used nested LinearLayouts. For just showing a view like that performance might not be an issue at all.

Comment: It won't work because it does not respect the weight-Attribute of children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom compound control.

Check the following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Make the control fill the available space. Make it to have 12 buttons. Calculate the size and position of them based on their position and the available space.

Depending on your needs you might also need to override onMeasure() and onLayout() defined earlier in the above document, in the "Fully Customized Components" section.

Comment: Technically this is a valid solution. I should have been more clear in my question, I'm mostly interested in doing this in XML. Writing any classes is probably overkill, since I already have a working layout based on nested LinearLayouts.

Comment: Well, if you don't want a proper solution, why do you ask? This is the only right way to do it.

Comment: Didn't mean to be picky, that's why I upvoted the answer when I commented. I was just hoping there was a way to do this in XML that I overlooked. Thanks for pointing out this way to solve the problem.