# How to stretch rows of a grid view in android where gridview contains buttons

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to design a calculator with buttons inside a grid view 4x4. Now when I generate the view there is white space below the grid. I want the grid to completely fill the parent. Just like http://rechner-app.com/ example. How to do this.

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMemory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grdButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0.5dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0.5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes

        btn = new Button(mContext);
        KeypadButton keypadButton = mButtons[position];

        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keypad1);

        // Set OnClickListener of the button to mOnButtonClick
        if (keypadButton != KeypadButton.DUMMY)
            btn.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClick);
        else
            btn.setClickable(false);
        // Set CalculatorButton enumeration as tag of the button so that we
        // will use this information from our main view to identify what to
        // do
        btn.setTag(keypadButton);
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        GridView mKeypadGridContainer = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grdButtons);
        Log.d(TAG, mKeypadGridContainer.getHeight() + "sadsd");
        Log.d(TAG, mKeypadGridContainer.getHeight() + " :height");
        //btn.setMinimumHeight(MainActivity.metricsHeight/4);
    } else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }

    btn.setText(mButtons[position].getText());
    return btn;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using GridView instead of a TableLayout?

Comment: Will the table layout resize itself. I will give it a try

Comment: imho i use GridView for "x" data, where x is unknown; in your case you know the number of buttons wich compose your layout, so why not use TableLayout and play with is components (of course use TableRow).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom compound control. See my answer here:

[How to create a regular, resizable grid without nested weights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023577/how-to-create-a-regular-resizable-grid-without-nested-weights/17025071#17025071)

UPDATE

This seems to be a nice tutorial:

http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/1696552527/implement-your-own-android-layouts

You will have to modify it to your needs and you will need to understand how onMeasure and onLayout works, but once you understood it, everything is falling into place, and it's easy.

I had a project where I had to construct such a control. If I remember well, I called the childrens' onMeasure method with the measure() method first in the parent's onMeasure() method using the MeasureSpec class, then I used the results in the parent's onLayout() using the getMeasuresWidth() and -Height() methods, which contained the measured dimensions. That's all in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me an example with code. That will be really helpful. I was thinking if I could use the xml to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

public class ResizeableGridView extends GridView {

```
private int height;

public ResizeableGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     height = getHeight();
}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    View v = getChildAt(0);
    if((v.getHeight()*5) < height){
        //if the combined height of rows is less than parent then only resize the children to fit parent
        int count = getChildCount();
        for(int i = 0;i < count;i++){
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            //I am using 5 because i used it for calendar and it has exactly five rows
            params.height = height/5;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }//end for
    }//end if
 } // end layoutChildren
} //end GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Number of columns must be set on your xml:

```
<AutoAdjustableGridView
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="3"/>
```

Extend GridView.

Divide your childCount by your number of columns to get your number of rows.

Divide the GridView's height by the number of rows.

Set the result as the child's height.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

/**
 * by Yuri Kayel on 26/01/2017.
*/
public class AutoAdjustableGridView extends GridView {

int childCount;
int columns;
int rows;
int gridViewHeight;
int gridViewWidth;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams childParams;

public AutoAdjustableGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AutoAdjustableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AutoAdjustableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public AutoAdjustableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    childCount = getChildCount();
    gridViewHeight = getHeight();
    gridViewWidth = getWidth();
    columns = getNumColumns();
    rows = childCount / columns;
}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        childParams = child.getLayoutParams();
        childParams.height = gridViewHeight / rows;
        childParams.width = gridViewWidth / columns;
        child.setLayoutParams(childParams);
    }
}
```

}